# Is there any way to convert maven project to pipeline in an automated way

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Having some maven projects. I want to change it to a scripted pipeline in jenkins

Comment: Please be more specific wrt the question. Your question is open ended. Here are some details wrt the solution you are looking for https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/

Answer (score 2):

To automate the following example you can use the Jenkins API via the groovy script console or an groovy system script to create you jobs programmatically.

Example for scripted Pipeline:

```
node{
  stage ('Build') {

    git url: 'https://github.com/cyrille-leclerc/multi-module-maven-project'

    withMaven(
        // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
        maven: 'M3',
        // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
        // Maven settings and global settings can also be defined in Jenkins Global Tools Configuration
        mavenSettingsConfig: 'my-maven-settings',
        mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

      // Run the maven build
      sh "mvn clean install"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe & FindBugs reports...
  }
}
```

You need the Pipeline Maven Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin